# Is the Actual culture related SQL to CLR float-double conversions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, clr

I am working on a ASP.Net WebForms legacy App and i need to retrofit one new feature into it. I am using a generated DataSet (Using VS 2013) to bridge the gap between ReportViewer and SQL server (Local reports, rdlc).

Everything Works nicely except one thing: Float conversions. On two Windows 8.1 En_US systems -10.5 (One of the values in a column) is seen on the report as -10.5 but on the server (Win 7 SP1 Es_CO) it displays as -105 even though the query *is* returning -10.5 on the server's local SQL instance.

I've checked out the generated code for the dataset and it casts an object from the datarows straight into double so i am assuming SQL server already handles the conversión (Via a CAST instruction on each column)

Is there anything i can do about it? It is worth mentioning all requests to the server (Win7 machine) came from one Win8.1 En_US machine.

Status update:
I am hinted (Not completely sure) that the fault is in the conversion from SQL to CLR types, as marking the report column as String yields the same result.

Comment: What value does the debugger tell you when you hit a breakpoint?

Comment: Have not yet been able to trigger breakpoints nor Trace/Debug calls on the generated source. It's been nigh impossible to diagnose this issue

Comment: It sounds like your .net application runs a different Globalization culture than the SQL Server does. Try setting the culture specifically in the thread for your website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You can also provide NumberFormatInfo to the casts if you'd prefer

Comment: @Allan- I do not agree on this solution and have personal experience of this. Setting culture whatever required introduces more bugs and confusion and need full attention when switching cultures.Consider this is happening for 500+ pages. Solution is to treat with invariant culture and format for display.

Comment: @Amit Globalization is for formatting. It doesn't change datatypes. When displaying datatypes, you re talking formatting and then you're talking Globalization.

Comment: @Allan-Formatting is correct but consider two threads UI in one language and server is in another language. How many times you will format? One at the time of display and one at the time of submission. Right. So each time you do this you need to be careful. So my point was just do formatting only at the time of displaying. While passing to server parse date with invariant culture and send.

Comment: @Allan- Also consider that there are different rules for thousand separator and decimal seprator across langauge. For one language "." can be decimal separator , for other it can be thousand separator and vice versa. So in this case data type will not change but parsing across different thread culture will result different output.

Comment: @Amit That's exactly the reason to use globalization, so when ever you interact with a specific entity (user, systems) you can handle things in "his" culture. Remember, you don't always have control over each part of a flow. Third party applications, systems, ETL processes exists. And when you need to get it through any type of string or formatting, you will have to consider globalization.

Comment: @Allan- That is what I said. We can handle things in his culture that is for display, presentation or output. Question is about inputs. If you treat all inputs in different different language then DB will be mess. If you treat input also in one culture and tomorrow server location shifted from one location to other with different culture then ? So, suggested to use invariant culture for inputs i.e. UI to Web server to SQL.

Comment: @Amit Yes, and here it's presentation (reporting) differences across servers as he's using double in the dataset but it's presented differently per server. Hence - I suggested globalization.

Answer (score 1):

I would want to know what the Type of the column in the DataSet was, and track that through until it arrives at the report. Is the web server on the same machine as the database, or is it on a different server? Maybe you use WCF to transfer that DataSet between the two. Also check the locale of the Report in the designer (look at Properties), and the data type that is being used for that field in the report (I just poke around in the XML of the RDLC file).

We had a similar issue where values with decimal places (like "10.5" became "105" when the value was serialized and deserialized without paying enough attention to the locale. For example, if you parse "10.5" in German, it will interpret the "." as a thousand separator, and ignore it, giving you the result "105". I'm guessing it's the same in es-CO.

Answer (score 0):

This situation comes in cross laguage scenario where your UI thread culture is different from processing thread or server thread. Use consistent Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture while passing data from UI to server to SQL and format only when displaying on UI.

One more recommendation is to use decimal at SQL end.

Hope this helps.