# C# Converting decimal 0 to string adds a thousand seperator and lots of 0's

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, openxml-sdk

I have an issue where a decimal 0, when converted to a string, adds a thousands separator (Danish formatting judging by how other values are converted) and lots of trailing 0's.
From the data i have so far, it looks like it has something to do with the fact that data is coming from MSSQL but that's just speculation on my part.

What i'm doing is this:

1. Data is stored in a MSSQL Database.
2. I load this data into my C# application using EntityFramework 6.0
3. Data is then converted into a DataTable - Datatypes on the columns match the datatype for the corresponding properties on the POCO entity.
4. Data in the DataTable is then written to an Excel sheet using OpenXml.

Showing the data inside the application is no problem but in Excel we are experiencing the aforementioned issue where the decimal value 0 is displayed as 0.00000000000000000000

First off, all values are converted to strings when written to Excel using the following code.

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", obj);
```

Values like 0.1 are saved to Excel as 0,1 (Danish formatting) and is displayed in the cell as 0,100 just as expected but all 0 values are both stored and displayed as 0.00000000000000000000.

Setting a break point at the code above shows *obj* to be 0 and if i convert it to a decimal it is zero but as soon as i convert it to a string i get the representation above and it doesn't matter if i use Invariant culture, da-DK or en-US.

The interesting thing is that if i add some code (see below) between step 3 and 4, that replaces all 0 values with a new 0 value then the value is converted correctly and is displayed in Excel as 0

```
foreach (DataRow row in projektTable.Rows)
  foreach (DataColumn column in projektTable.Columns)
    if (column.DataType == typeof(decimal))
      if (row.Field<decimal>(column) == 0)
        row.SetField<decimal>(column, 0);
```

I hope someone has the brilliant insight that i am lacking as i do not understand why 2 decimal 0's can be converted to 2 different string representations.

edit: Sorry for forgetting the database type. The column is a decimal(18,4).

edit 2: Just to be clear. At no point do i do something like decimal.Parse or anything like that.
Data i loaded via EF so datatypes are strongly typed because of the properties on the entities. Data is then loaded into at DataTable - Types for the columns are found using reflection on the properties.
Data is then written to Excel by using row[rowX][columnX] to get the value as an object (not caring if the value is a decimal, datetime, string, etc). That object is then converted to a string using the string.Format() code i posted above.

Comment: What is the type in the database? If you use `decimal.GetBits` with the value fetched by EF, what's the result?

Comment: Any scientist will tell you that they are *not* the same number.  They are very used to the idea that nature doesn't count with 10 fingers and that any measurement is imprecise.  And 0.00000000000000000000 is a wholeheckofalot more precise than 0.  Something that *decimal* as well as Excel know about.  Probable mishap is that the dbase column is a string and not a number so you are duplicating a bug in whatever code wrote the value.   And that you might not want to ignore the *format* of the Excel cell.

Comment: We already discussed part similar to this. Hope it will give some insights.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634432/is-the-actual-culture-related-sql-to-clr-float-double-conversions?noredirect=1#comment44601814_21634432. Also, when we faced this situation not for excel though but we used amount.ToString("N", nfi) where nfi is NumberFormatInfo and that we have set properties and provided as input.

Comment: *"i do not understand why 2 decimal 0's can be converted to 2 different string representations"* - that's standard behaviour  - a `decimal` "knows" how precise it is, so although `1m == 1.000m` the two have different representations in memory and `ToString()` reveals their precision. The interesting questions are *"why am I getting twenty `0`s instead of four?"* and *"why am I only getting them on zero values?"*, because when I tried this I (a) got `x` zeroes from a `decimal(18, x)` SQL column and (b) got them on both `0m` and `1m` inputs.